# Count Consecutive Months with Gaps

Tags: sql

Consider a table with two columns, **Case Number** and **Occurrence Month**:

| Case Number | Occurrence Month |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | 201801 |
| 123 | 201802 |
| 123 | 201803 |
| 123 | 201805 |
| 123 | 201806 |

I'd like to create a third column that shows for each Case Number on a given Occurrence Month how many consecutive months it has been. I used the following simple query:

```
SELECT CaseNumber, 
       OccurenceMonth, 
       COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY CaseNumber ORDER BY OccurenceMonth) AS ConsecutiveMonths
FROM table
ORDER BY CaseNumber, OccurrenceMonth;
```

This produces a table that looks like so:

| Case Number | Occurrence Month | Consecutive Months |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 201801 | 1 |
| 123 | 201802 | 2 |
| 123 | 201803 | 3 |
| 123 | 201805 | 4 |
| 123 | 201806 | 5 |

I'd like, however, the counting of Consecutive Months to reset between Occurrence Months 201803 and 201805 so that it looks like so:

| Case Number | Occurrence Month | Consecutive Months |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 201801 | 1 |
| 123 | 201802 | 2 |
| 123 | 201803 | 3 |
| 123 | 201805 | 1 |
| 123 | 201806 | 2 |

From my understanding this simple change will make the query much more complicated. Any ideas on the best way to do this? Thank you.

Comment: What is the data type of occurrence month?  Also tag with the database you are using.

Comment: @GordonLinoff it is a converted datetime into the YYYYMM format.

LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, OccurrenceDatetime, 112), 6)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the code in the comment, you appear to be using SQL Server.

An observation helps solve this problem.  If you subtracted a sequence of numbers (say the "row number") from each row, then the result would be constant where the months are incrementing.  Voila!  We can use this observation to implement a solution using window functions:

```
select t.*,
       row_number() over (partition by case_number
                                       dateadd(month, - seqnum, cast(yyyymm + '01' as date))
                          order by yyyymm
                         ) as consecutive_months
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by case_number order by yyyymm) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t;
```

Comment: Gordon, this worked perfectly. Thank you so much for your response. I'm going to mark your answer as accepted.